# Why does turning on Prestashop's Geolocation by IP Address gave me a 503 error on PageSpeed Insight?

Tags: geolocation

I am running PrestaShop 1.6.1.5 and got my Google Ads disapproved
Here is the error message on Google Ads back end:
Destination not working
Platform: iOS
HTTP error 503

This error vanishes when GeoLocation feature is disabled.
But I need it to redirect users from the wrong country.

Answer (score 0):

You might be blocking the IP address of Google Ads robot. It is causing 503 and thus Google Ads rejected the ads.

Please make sure you do not redirect robots IP address ranges or country where the robots coming from.